# How do I test the microphone in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I attached a microphone to my computer, and it was detected.  It's all setup, now I want to test that it's actually working, and that it's working well.  I tried sound recorder, but it didn't record any sound.  I still think it's working though.  What other ways can I test the microphone?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right-click on the volume thing in your [taskbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar), and select "recording devices".

This will open a dialog box with four tabs. Make sure the second tab "Recording" is selected. There you should see your microphone, with a bar showing if it is receiving sound or not. You can also check its properties here.

If your system allows "Monitoring" that will echo the microphone through your own speakers to test.